# Displaying Variables in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to display the value of a Variable inside my GLUT window.

Perhaps something like the text display function..

Text Display Function:

```
renderBitmapString(0, 0.8, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, "hello");
```

Defined as:

```
    void renderBitmapString(float x, float y, void *font, char *string) 
{  
  char *c;
  glRasterPos2f(x,y);
  for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) 
  {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can print the variable into a char[] with sprintf,

```
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer,"%s", myVariable);
```

And then call the renderBitmapString on it.

Comment: This is assuming your myVariable is a char[] string.  If your variable is an int, use "%d" instead of "%s".  If it's a float use "%f", etc.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your responses!

Comment: @user605839: don't forget to "accept" the answer if it helps you. If it doesn't help, please describe in more detail what you want (how does the code you showed fail to meet your requirements?)

Answer (score 0):

First, a normal C++ string can be turned into a char * using c_str: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ However, note that this gives you a **const** char*, so you'll have to use const_cast().

```
string a ("Hello");
renderBitmapString(0, 0.8, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, const_cast<char*>(a.c_str()));
```

Pretty ugly IMO.

Second, I wouldn't use char * in a C++ program. Instead, you can modify your procedure in a number of ways. Personally, I would use a string iterator.

```
void renderBitmapString(float x, float y, void *font, string str) 
{
  glRasterPos2f(x,y);
  for (string::iterator c = (&str)->begin(); c != (&str)->end(); ++c) 
  {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
  }
}

string a ("Hello");
renderBitmapString(0, 0.8, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function and variables like that:

```
// global variables
int text_x = 0, text_y = 0;
char text[] = "Text location:";

// to display strings with variables
void print_str(int x, int y, void *font, char *string, ...)
{
    int len, i;

    va_list st;
    va_start(st, string);
    char str[1024];
    vsprintf_s(str, string, st);
    va_end(st);

    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    len = (int)strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, str[i]);
}
```

than you can use the function as shown below:

```
print_str(text_x, text_y, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, "%s %d x %d", text, text_x, text_y);
```